# How to get the count of a class with AppleScript?

Tags: css, html, count, applescript, bbedit

Learning AppleScript I'm trying to practice and I wanted to see if I could get the count of a class in an `.xhtml` file.

In my BBEdit project I set a variable for the project with:

```
set this_project to file of project document 1
```

made sure to target all the `.xhtml` files with:

```
set total_xhtml to {search mode:grep, case sensitive:false, match words:false, extend selection:false, returning results:true, filter:{ID:"111232452", filter_mode:and_mode, filter_terms:{{operand:"xhtml", field:«constant ****FnSf», operator:op_is_equal}}}}
```

but when I try to count the class for each file I'm stumped..

I did try:

```
set varCount to count class=\"foobar\"" of (this_project in total_xhtml)
```

If I try `set varCount to count class=\"foobar\""` it returns a number in the AppleScript Editor but how can I get the full count for each file in a project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realized I never accepted an answer to my question and I wanted to close out this Q&A.  I didn't choose the provided [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25050106/1952287) because `text item delimiters` were firing an incorrect count from the file and I wanted an approach that didn't call on a `do shell`.

In AppleScript and BBEdit if you reference the Dictionary there is `FIND`:

[image]

and with a repeat loop I was able to step through each occurrence of `class="foobar"`:

```
## beginning of file
select insertion point before first character of text document text document 1 

set countClass to 0

repeat
    ## find pattern
    set findClass to find "class=\"foobar\"" searching in text 1 of text document text document 1 options {options} with selecting match 

    ## exit after no more patterns
    if not found of findClass then exit repeat 

    ## increment for every occurrence
    set countClass to countClass + 1 
end repeat

## return total count of pattern
return countClass
```

With the above repeat I was able to step through each file and total up every occurrence of class `foobar`.  Hope this helps the next person.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're asking, you want to find out how many times your class is listed in your different .xhtml files.

If that's what you're trying to accomplish, the below is a working example that should do what you're looking for.

```
on run
     try
         set foundItems to do shell script "grep -ri 'yourClassName' " & quoted form of "/Path/to/Your/directory"
     on error
         set foundItems to ""
     end try

     set oldDelims to AppleScript's text item delimiters -- save their current state
     set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {return} -- declare new delimiters
     set tempList to every text item of foundItems
     set AppleScript's text item delimiters to oldDelims -- restore them

     set foundCount to count of tempList
end run
```